# Twitter streaming api node.js - Slow the stream down

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twitter, socket.io

I'm making an app that allows you to search a location then shows a filtered twitter feed relating to the location, the problem is on a search like 'London' there are so many realtime tweets that the feed moves so quickly that you cant read them.

I don't know if I should stop and start the socket? Or push all the tweets into an array on the front then append them, but the array could quite easily get too big. Also some searches will be really slow so this need not happen all the time.

I have built it with node and express, any thought of how to cope with this amount if data would be appreciated.

Example code - Backend

```
    var place = [ '-122.75', '36.8', '-121.75', '37.8' ]
    var stream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { locations: place, language: 'en' })

   stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
     console.log(tweet)
   })

   io.on('connect', function(socket) {

  // this is coming from the twit module. 
  // 'tweet' is one of the events it listens to
     stream.on('tweet', function(status) {

   // this is our own channel we set up to to send the tweets down to the client
    var data = {};
    data.name = status.user.name;
    data.screen_name = status.user.screen_name;
    data.text = status.text;
    data.user_profile_image = status.user.profile_image_url;

    socket.emit('statuses', data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using readable.pause() function - here more reference to it: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause

Basically you can pause the stream with .pause() and when you're able to read again, you can call .resume().

Another idea would be filtering the data somehow. When you slow it down, after an hour you will be an hour behind the "main stream".